# jquery confirmation cancel still submits the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

even if i cancel my confirmation the form is still submitted
what is the problem? i think my jquery is wrong pls help

my button outside the form

```html
<li><a id="recieve_btn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn animated infinite pulse" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> Recieve</a></li>
```

my form

```html
<form id="frm-list" action="<?php echo base_url('home/recieve') ?>">
  <table class="table table-condensed display dataTable dt-checkboxes-select" id="list" style="width: 100%;"> 
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Family Name</th>
    <th>Given Name</th>
    <th>Middle Initial</th>
    <th>Birthdate</th>
    <th>Module Enrolled</th>
    <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="datatable">
  <?php foreach ($result as $trainee): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $trainee->no ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trainee->lname ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trainee->fname ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trainee->mi ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trainee->bdate ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trainee->module ?></td>
    <td>
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm animated infinite pulse" data-registerid="<?php echo $trainee->no ?>" id="update">Update</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?> 
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Family Name</th>
    <th>Given Name</th>
    <th>Middle Initial</th>
    <th>Birthdate</th>
    <th>Module Enrolled</th>
    <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
 </form>
```

my jquery for submitting the form

```html
$(document).on('click', '#recieve_btn', function(){
   $('#frm-list').trigger('submit');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix inline Java Script code with jQuery, try below instead:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#recieve_btn', function() {
  //$('#frm-list').trigger('submit');
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    console.log('confirmed');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('unconfirmed');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a id="recieve_btn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn animated infinite pulse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> Recieve</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. it may help you.

```
$(document).on('click', '#recieve_btn', function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    $('#frm-list').trigger('submit');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: only return false, if do not want to submit.